# new item in onCreateViewHolder recycleview multi type android

Tags: android

I use multi type item in recycleview. When i scroll all item of recycleview continue I scroll again ( not add item) all item of recycleview then it call back mothod onCreateViewHolder(..). why does it call back mothod onCreateViewHolder(..) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multi type. The first time you use a ViewHolder of some other type - onCreateViewHolder will be called. I assume that you distinguish between types using position, In that case the first time your recycler view encounters position on a new type it calls onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: But when I scroll again, reccycleview call back onCreateViewHolder and it makes my list verry slow. Do you have orther solution that? help me!

Comment: in getItemViewType method, I make: return items.get(position).getTypeLayout();